# Jasper report no encuentra el archivo en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

Tengo este error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: report_ASISTENCIA.jrxml (El sistema no
>   puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

No se porqué no encuentra el archivo luego de ejecutar este codigo:

```
try {
    JasperReport reporte=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report_ASISTENCIA.jrxml");
    // JasperReport reporte=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("reporteasistencia_alumnos.jrxml");
    JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,null,this.cn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(print);            
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Lo que te está ocurriendo es que no se puede localizar el archivo a partir de la ruta relativa que has definido. En java este tema es un tanto confuso. Te recomiendo que agregues una foto con la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto para poder identificar en donde está tu archivo y en base a eso darte una solución.

Comment: agrega la estructura de tu proyecto y con qué lo estás construyendo, por ejemplo, maven, gradle, etc

Answer (score 0):

Segun la [documentacion](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html#compileReport-java.lang.String-), el path toma como referencia la raiz de tu codigo fuente, es decir src(en el caso de maven)

Comment: en el caso de meven igual se puede poner en la carpeta de recursos

Comment: Con Maven no es así porque el código no se ejecuta desde src sino desde target.

Comment: Maven te permite organizar tu proyecto de una forma estandar, a nivel de root existen una carpeta src la cual contiene dos carpetas: main y test, en cada una de ellas existen tambien a su vez dos carpetas: java y resources(existe una tercera llamada filters aunque no es muy comun que se use), en resources es donde debes colocar todos los archivos que no son .java, en el caso de @E.Betanzos debes poner tus archivos de jasper aqui y maven en la fase de compilacion va a dejar todos los archivos .class y lo que hay en resources en la carpeta target.